# What is the minimal conditions on holomorphic $f,g$ such that $h(z,w)=f(z)+g(w)$ is real?

Tags: complex-analysis

I took a course of Complex Analysis around a year ago, and have forgotten everything ever since. Today, I have been thinking about a question that I had come up with earlier, which I have no idea how to solve. I'm pretty sure I know the solution, intuitively, but I don't know how to prove it. I'm really curious if it is something that I'm able to prove using the standard tools that the course granted me with.

Let $z$ and $w$ be independent complex variables, and let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic one-variable complex functions. Define $h(z,w)=f(z)+g(w)$. What is the sufficient and necessary conditions on $f$ and $g$ such that $h(z,w)$ is real?

- The fact that $z$ and $w$ are independent forbiddens solutions in which $z=\bar{w}$, for instance. The variables cannot be related.
- The only possible solution that I have thought of is that both $f$ and $g$ must be constant, such that $\Im{\{f+g\}}=0$. Not sure how to prove this is the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first prove the basic statement:

> The image of any non-constant holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Indeed, if the function, say f, has an essential singularity at the infinity, you can apply the [Casorati-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Otherwise, the function $f$ is polynomial and the fundamental theorem of Algebra shows that $f$ is actually surjective.

Now apply this statement with the restriction of $h$ along any line passing through the origin. You deduce that $h$ has to be constant along any of these lines and, by continuity, $h$ itself is constant. So $f$ and $g$ are constant as well.